# Clock resets To UTC on Reboot

Tags: time, timezone

I've newly installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 on two hosts, desktop on one, server on another. The timezone on the server resets to UTC on each boot.

```
# cat /etc/timezone
America/Los_Angeles

# ls -la /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Sep  2 22:47 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles
```

I've run `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` several times. I've tried `timedatectl set-timezone "America/Los_Angeles"` too.

`timedatectl` shows:

```
                      Local time: Mon 2019-09-02 23:00:54 America
                  Universal time: Mon 2019-09-02 23:00:54 UTC
                        RTC time: Mon 2019-09-02 16:00:44
                       Time zone: America/Los_Angeles (America, +0000)
       System clock synchronized: no
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: yes
```

I can't get the Local Time to show PDT like the desktop? I do have NTP installed and configured.

==========================

Thank you Byte Commander for the clarifying edits. But I still need to find an answer.

```
    $ date
Tue Sep  3 20:18:13 UTC 2019
```

Shows UTC instead of PDT like it should.

==================================

On a whim, I tried renaming /etc/timezone and /etc/localtime. I re-ran dpkg-reconfigure tzdata. The files were recreated. Date still shows UTC.

Comment: Normally on a server the RTC should be in UTC (the only reason to keep the RTC in local is to accommodate Windows in a dual-boot machine). So as a first measure do `sudo timedatectl  set-local-rtc false`.

Comment: In this case the server is going to be a DVR needing local time to correctly perform recordings.

Comment: This is a different issue. When applications ask the time to the kernel, the kernel applies the TZ to the UTC time from the RTC, so they never see the RTC. Of course your specific TZ seems hosed (PDT/Los Angles is UTC -0700, not UTC +0000). My own PC has its RTC set to UTC, but all my apps see my local time (UTC+0200).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I fixed it with:

```
apt install --reinstall tzdata
```

Resulting in:

```
    # timedatectl
                      Local time: Wed 2019-09-04 08:42:58 PDT
                  Universal time: Wed 2019-09-04 15:42:58 UTC
                        RTC time: Wed 2019-09-04 15:42:58
                       Time zone: America/Los_Angeles (PDT, -0700)
       System clock synchronized: no
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
RTC in local TZ: no
```