# RTC set to something weird

Tags: virtualization, vmware, time, rtc

Running 22.04.1, reinstalled tzdata (per [Clock resets To UTC on Reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1170398/clock-resets-to-utc-on-reboot/1443510#1443510)) but still getting something really weird - I though the RTC was getting set to UTC, but it's almost the opposite, being 7 1/2 hrs the other direction:

```
# timedatectl
               Local time: Thu 2022-12-01 17:21:37 PST
           Universal time: Fri 2022-12-02 01:21:37 UTC
                 RTC time: Fri 2022-12-02 08:43:19
                Time zone: America/Los_Angeles (PST, -0800)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: n/a
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

[Why does local time reset itself to wrong time after "timedatectl set-time"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1330089/why-does-local-time-reset-itself-to-wrong-time-after-timedatectl-set-time) suggests that I should use timesyncd instead of openntpd, however when I run "timedatectl set-ntp true" it says "ntp not supported", though removing openntpd did get the rtc synchronized, and it stayed that way after I reinstalled openntpd.

I'm curious what's going on here...

Comment: Are you dualbooting with Windows?

Comment: No, it's a vmware vm